# Induction on two statements at once

Tags: induction

Suppose that I wanted to prove $P(n)$ is true, but I need some $Q(n)$ to be true so that I can show $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$. Is it always okay for me to do

$$P(n) \land Q(n) \implies P(n+1) \land Q(n+1)$$

to show that $P(n) \land Q(n)$ are true and then extract $P(n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you prove $P(0) \land Q(0)$.  It occurs with some frequency in inductive proofs that it's easier to prove more than you want (because then you have more hypotheses to work with).

Comment: Certainly. If you set $R(n) := P(n) \land Q(n)$ then your implication can be written $R(n) \implies R(n+1),$ which is on the ordinary form.